# Программное изменение Z-координаты виджетов

Tags: qt

Как изменить расположение виджетов друг относительно друга по Z-координате?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Метод [`void QWidget::raise()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) поднимает виджет на вершину стека виджетов внутри родительского виджета.
- Метод [`void QWidget::lower()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#lower) опускает виджет на "дно" стека виджетов внутри родительского виджета.
- Метод [`void QWidget::stackUnder(QWidget * w)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#stackUnder) перемещает виджет под виджет `w` внутри стека виджетов внутри родительского виджета.